# Use of np.r_ and np.c_ VS hstack and vstack in python. On using both gives same output

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am using python3 and found that (np.r_ and vstack) and (np.c_ and hstack) gives same output.
Is there any explicit difference of usage or its same.
And where to use n when.
Can someone please explain this.
Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: They are different ways of using `np.concatenate`.  They just tweak the inputs in different ways, as documented.

Comment: You can also study the code

Comment: Thanks, any references to study on those?

Comment: Might as well take a look at the source: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py

Comment: Your IDE (`jupyter/ipython`?) makes it easy to check both docs and code. The main documentation has `[source]` links.  And as commented, `github` has all the code.

Comment: I am using Jupyter

Comment: c_ behaves almost exactly like hstack, with the addition of range
literals being allowed.